# Pythagoras check Haskell

Tags: haskell

Started using Haskell recently and I'm having a problem with a couple of the basics.

I wrote a simple program to square a variable called 'square'. Now I'm trying to write a program called pyth that takes 3 variables inputs them all in square and then adds a squared to b squared to see if it is equal to c squared to determine if they form a Pythagoras triple.

```
square :: Int -> Int
square x = x*x

pyth :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
pyth a b c
a = square a  
b = square b 
c = square c
a+b == c = True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question doesn't really contain any question, but from what you wrote, it's clear that you're struggling with Haskell's syntax.

My guess from looking at your code is that you're mixing up Haskell's pattern matching syntax with a sequence of statements typical of an imperative language.
What you're trying to achieve can be done in the following way:

```
square :: Int -> Int
square x = x*x 

pyth :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
pyth a b c = a' + b' == c'
     where a' = square a  
           b' = square b 
           c' = square c
```

Note that `a'` is a regular variable in Haskell, `'` being a valid character in identifiers. This example is the same as having written the function as:

```
pyth :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
pyth a b c = (square a) + (square b) == (square c)
```

As you can see, there is no sequence of statements and the function is a single expression. We use `where` to extract subexpressions from the expression we are writing and give them a name for readability or to avoid repetition, for example, but it does not mean that they will be evaluated in order or that one of them is the result. Even if you had written it like this:

```
pyth :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
pyth a b c = result
    where a' = square a
          b' = square b
          c' = square c
          result = a' + b' == c'
```

It's all a single expression and it could have been written in any order. Like the following:

```
pyth :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
pyth a b c = result
    where result = a' + b' == c'
          a' = square a
          b' = square b
          c' = square c
```

I suggest going through [Learn you a haskell](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com). It's a very good resource for a beginner.

Comment: The code of the first and third definition of `pyth` is wrong (missing ' in the comparison)

Answer (score 4):

You are making some syntax error. A correct version of your `pyth` function will look like this:

```
pyth :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
pyth a b c = a' + b' == c'
    where
      a' = square a  
      b' = square b 
      c' = square c
```

Note that I have changed the variable names and have added a `where` block where you store the squared values. In the main function body (`a' + b' == c'`), you do the actual check for the Pythagoras theorem.